# _progres.exe command line paramaters

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have the following command:

```
_progres.exe -b -s 128 -p test.p -db testDB.db
```

I would like to know how the -s command is being used, and where I can find any other documentation on all of the command line parameters for _progres.exe.

Comment: These are known as startup parameters in Progress Openedge

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/2743.openedge-11-6-product-documentation for the complete OpenEdge documentation. Download the "Startup Command and Parameter Reference" from https://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge116/pdfs/dpspr/dpspr.pdf

From there:

Use Stack Size (-s) to change the size of the stack (an internal memory area used by ABL program modules)

Or: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P42732